# Added video to Unity as an asset

Tags: c#, unity

I am unable to run the video. Here is the detailed definition. What should I write to run it?

After moving script file to plane, I get this debug output:

[image: This is my debug output]

Here is the code on my button which is related to the plane object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MovieTexture movie;

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = movie as MovieTexture;
        movie.Play();
    }
}
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBc3ubr18ks) and getting an "Unassigned reference error".

Comment: Can you include the *actual error* as it appears? As it stands, it sounds like you might have declared `public MovieTexture`, but have not actually linked a movie texture via the inspector.

Comment: unable to link it using unity ui it says None(Movie texture)

Answer (score 2):

## Docs

The Unity documentation is very good. To play videos in unity you must use a `MovieTexture`

The [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) provides a lot more information, but I shall summarise it here.

## How to

First import the movie file, this requires QuickTime

> Video files are imported via Apple QuickTime. Supported file types are what your QuickTime installation can play (usually .mov, .mpg, .mpeg, .mp4, .avi, .asf). On Windows movie importing requires Quicktime to be installed ([download here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/quicktime)).

Then create a material for the movie and drag the movie asset to the texture argument (This albedo in the Unity 5 standard shader)

Drag that material onto the object you wish to show the movie on

Then add the following script to the game object which has the movie material on

```
// Use this for initialization
MovieTexture movie; //This is private as we get the movie texture from the renderer

void Start () {
    Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>(); //The renderer will give us access to the material
    movie = (MovieTexture)r.material.mainTexture; //Get the texture and cast it to a MovieTexture

    if (movie == null) //Check the texure exists and is a MovieTexture
    {
        Debug.LogError("There is no movie texture on the material");
        Debug.Break(); //Pause the editor
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (movie.isPlaying)
        {
            movie.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            movie.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to show only a more advanced implementation of what the asker is already doing. If calling `movie.Play()` doesn't work *at all*, checking if `movie.IsPlaying` first surely does nothing to help. In fact, the error code *Unassigned Reference* tells us the problem is unrelated.

Comment: Gnemlock, I understand that, however it seemed the asker was very sketchy on what they currently had, so I have also explained how the the MovieTexture works inside unity and provided a doc link

Comment: getting object reference error. 
       Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
       MovieTexture movie = r.material.mainTexture as MovieTexture;
       movie.Play();

Comment: public MovieTexture movie; after adding this it says none in the plane.

Comment: I've updated my answer - if you're still stuck I can add screenshots. Feel free to ask if there's anything you don't understand